# Email Activity has to be created on case whenever an email has been sent through workflow

Tags: apex, community, workflow, case, activities

We have a workflow on case object with multiple time triggers.So,we need to create an email task on the case object.Whenever email has been sent through workflow before it was working fine.Now,the email activity is not creating on the case object whenever email has been sent.

I had gone through some other websites but they are specifying to assign a task to the contact record of system administrator.But, we need to create an activity for the same object.

For reference:
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h2Lb

I tried using as per @Pete Fife discussed in above link.Duplicate email alert in workflow and using like thread id in email template like  ref: {!Case.Thread_Id}
But it is not also working.

Is there any possibility to achieve through configuration or what are the ways to achieve through customization.

Comment: Is the workflow's target object the `Case`?

Comment: @cropredy Yes.also i had tried with the following way but it doesn't works.success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h2LbAAI –

Comment: I had tried using thread id with in the template but nothing is working.Can you please look on this. @cropredy

Comment: Pavan -- your question is going to be closed unless you provide more details using [edit] including examples